# How to play FIFA on a basic laptop without over-heating the laptop?

Tags: fifa-12, fifa-17

I have a basic laptop with 4GB RAM. This laptop just can't handle graphics of Fifa-17, so I generally use Fifa-12 instead. Even then I have to decrease the resolution and disable finer animations, and still my laptop kinda heats up a lot.
This make my *Fifa playing experience* limited upto max 3hrs at a time.

I wonder if there is any trick to manage playing Fifa on a basic laptop without over-heating it -- other than obviously by upgrading the laptop itself.

PS: The solution could be some hack in fifa game or suggestion for a different Fifa-like soccer game all-together.

Comment: If your laptop doesn't meet the minimum specs for the game, we can't help.  Your only solution is to get another computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about trying to run a game on a system that doesn't meet the minimum requirements.  FIFA 17 needs a minimum of 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: Can you install more RAM? Your heating issue is likely being caused by your processor having to run full throttle to run the game.  So long as the system is running properly, it shouldn't allow itself to overheat (thermal throttling will kick in which would further degrade your performance).  Changing game settings won't alleviate any processing issue if you are already experiencing heating problems on minimum settings.  That being said, suggestions are also off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get a cooling pad.

I'm not sure whether or not you consider this an "upgrade", but cooling pads can be relatively inexpensive and should significantly increase the amount of time it takes to overheat. Otherwise, as long as there isn't anything wrong with the hardware (like being full of dust and lint), you can't really do much. The components in your computer will generate heat as you use them, and they will overheat eventually if playing Fifa on low settings generates more heat than your computer can shed.